# JSON data from Twitter to Edgelist?

Tags: python, json, twitter

Following along another code review ([Printing out JSON data from Twitter as a CSV](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/printing-out-json-data-from-twitter-as-a-csv)) I would like to submit a slightly adapted code for review.

This code imports JSON data obtained from Twitter and prints out just the tweet author and if there are any users the author mentions in the tweet.  User_mentions is a field that is provided in the JSON output.  The difficult part I've encountered is that an author sometimes doesn't mention anyone, or mentions 5 other user.  So I'm not sure of the best way to account for this, besides what I've cobbled together below.

**My ultimate goal:**
Create an edgelist from this data to then put into a network visualization tool. I've been converting the output (example below) from this code using a UNIX command (also below) I wrote, but if anyone has a better way to do this within this code, please do let me know.

**Format after code:**

- author1,mention1,mention2,mention3
- author1,mention4
- author2 author3,mention5
- author4,mention3,mention6

**Ultimate format in CSV:**

- author1,mention1
- author1,mention2
- author1,mention3
- author1,mention4
- author3,mention5
- author4,mention3
- author4,mention6

**Python Code:**

```
import json
import sys

tweets=[]

# import tweets from JSON
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
try:
    tweets.append(json.loads(line))
except:
pass

# create a new variable for a single tweets
tweet=tweets[0]

# pull out various data from the tweets
tweet_author = [tweet['user']['screen_name'] for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention1 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][0]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 1 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention2 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][1]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 2 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention3 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][2]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 3 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention4 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][3]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 4 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention5 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][4]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 5 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention6 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][5]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 6 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention7 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][6]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 7 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention8 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][7]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 8 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention9 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][8]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 9 else None) for tweet in tweets]
tweet_mention10 = [(tweet['entities']['user_mentions'][9]['screen_name'] if len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) >= 10 else None) for tweet in tweets]

#outputting to CSV
out = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

rows = zip(tweet_author, tweet_mention1, tweet_mention2, tweet_mention3,    tweet_mention4, tweet_mention5, tweet_mention6)

from csv import writer
csv = writer(out)

for row in rows:
    values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)

out.close()
```

**UNIX command:**
Used to take the output of this code and format as an edgelist. If this part can be worked into the above code, it would be much appreciated!

```
cat [file.txt] | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $1, $2 "##" $1, $3 "##" $1, $4 "##" $1, $5 "##" $1, $6 "##" $1, $7 "##" $1, $8 "##" $1, $9 "##" $1 $10}' | sed 's/##/\n/g' | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found another answer on https://github.com/alexhanna to this question  that I've been able to adapt and enrich to somewhat meet my needs:

```
import json
import sys
from csv import writer
import time
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as in_file, \
    open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out_file:
    print >> out_file
    csv = writer(out_file)
    tweet_count = 0

    for line in in_file:
        tweet_count += 1
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
        except:
            pass

        if not (isinstance(tweet, dict)):
            pass
        elif 'delete' in tweet:
            pass
        elif 'user' not in tweet:
            pass
        else:
            if 'entities' in tweet and len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) > 0:
                user = tweet['user']
                user_mentions = tweet['entities']['user_mentions']

                for u2 in user_mentions:
                    print ",".join([
                        user['screen_name'],
                        u2['screen_name']
                        ])

#values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
#csv.writerow(values)

print "File Imported:", str(sys.argv[1])
print "# Tweets Imported:", tweet_count
print "File Exported:", str(sys.argv[2])
print "Time Elapsed:", (datetime.now()-startTime)
```